# How do I make an image slide up when the caption is slide up?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've created the next html snippet: http://jsfiddle.net/4gDMK/
This works good, but I can't find a way to move the captions and the image the same time up, so that the image isn't fully visible anymore.

Here is the base html:

```
<figure>
    <img src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_1vc-O2P4PHQ/S1bI97AgDoI/AAAAAAAACxs/MOo533hzeSw/s200/technical_stockphoto2.jpg" alt="Stockphoto 1" />
    <figcaption>Caption text</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Look at this site for an example: http://etchapps.com/
On some blocks you can click, and then the caption is shown and the image goes up. This is what I need, but then on hover.

Does someone know how to make this?

With kind regards

Comment: Have you tried giving the image a negative `margin-top`?

Comment: The problem is that I need that the image is sliding up in the same speed and time as the caption. Look at [this site](http://etchapps.com/#studio) and click on an image, and you see what I mean :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, there are a lot of changes, so bear with me.

The CSS has been trimmed down to this (since we will do all the effects with JQuery):

```
figure {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width:200px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 20px;
}
figure img {
    display: block;
    max-width:200px;
}
figcaption {
    position: absolute;
    background: black;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    width:160px;
}
```

This will cause the caption to sit hidden out of site below the image until we are ready to show it.

Now for the javascript:

```
//Thanks roXon
$(function(){
    $('figure').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function( e ){
        var toPos = e.type=="mouseenter" ? $('figcaption',this).innerHeight() : 0 ;
        $('img', this).stop().animate({marginTop: -toPos}, 200);
    });
});
```

The causes any figure when hovered to raise up the height of the caption below it, thus showing the caption and hiding the top part of the image. When the mouse leaves we set the margin back to its default of 0.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NkXCd/1/

Using CSS3 instead of JQuery (again as per roXon's suggestion)

```
figure {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width:200px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 20px;
}
figure img {
    display:block;
    max-width:200px;
    margin-top:0;
       -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
           transition: 0.3s;  
}
figcaption {
    position: absolute;
    background: black;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    width:160px;
}

figure:hover img{
    margin-top:-40px;
}
```

CSS3 Fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/NkXCd/2/

Comment: And seeing the OP uses HTML5 than you can suggest also a CSS3 implementation instead of jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/NkXCd/2/ Using `transition`, quite cool!

Comment: @roXon That works great! I updated the answer to provide the CSS3 solution as well.

Comment: Thanks for providing kindly my suggestions into your answer! I would give you another +1 if I had that much :)